# How do I make a function recursive

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge set of data (almost 12k rows).  I want t search column A for a keyword (Ex: name") and then move its corresponding value from column B to a new sheet.  I have this working but can't figure out how to make it recursive so it looks at all 12k entries in column A.  Please help.

See script below that works, but needs to be recursive

```
Sub Test()

With Sheets("original")
    If .Range("A24").Value = "Name        " Then
        Sheets("new").Range("A1").Value = .Range("B24").Value
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like a filter would be an easier way to do this - simpler than looping through all rows. Also, just to note, recursion is not the same as iteration.

Comment: If you read all of `A:B` into an array, you can loop over it to create a new array of just the items that have `Name    ` in A and then you can paste just the second column into the new sheet.

Comment: Can someone please provide an example.  I am kind of new to this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop through the range of cells and use offset to get the value in column B to place in the new worksheet.  It doesn't need to be recursive

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1
    For Each c In Sheets("original").Range("A:A")
    If c.Value = "Name        " Then
        Sheets("new").Cells(iRow, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        'move to the next row
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here bis an example using standard 2-D arrays. A dictionary is another array based option. An AutoFilter or Advanced Filter removes the need for arrays and/or iteration through the rows.

Note that this does not loop through 'all the rows in column A'. It stops looping when there are no more values in column B that could be returned.

```
Sub Test2()
    '
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928149
    '

    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, bees As Variant

    With Worksheets("original")

        'collect source values
        arr = .Range(.Cells(7, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

        'prepare target array
        ReDim bees(1 To 1, 1 To 1)

        'loop through source value array and retain column B based on condition
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            'case insensitive comparison
            If LCase(arr(i, 1)) = LCase("Name        ") Then
                'assign column B value to target array
                bees(1, UBound(bees, 2)) = arr(i, 2)
                'make room for next matching value
                ReDim Preserve bees(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(bees, 2) + 1)
            End If
        Next i

        'trim off the last unused element of the target array
        ReDim Preserve bees(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(bees, 2) - 1)

    End With

    'add new worksheet at end of worksheets queue
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

        'rename new worksheet
        .Name = "bees"

        'put target array in new worksheet starting at A2
        .Cells(2, "A").Resize(UBound(bees, 2), UBound(bees, 1)) = _
            Application.Transpose(bees)

    End With

End Sub
```